# pyspark dataframe limiting on multiple columns

Tags: python, pyspark

I wonder if anyone point me in the right direction with the following problem. In a rather large pyspark dataframe with about 50 odd columns, two of them represent say 'make' and 'model'. Something like

```
21234234322(unique id) .. .. .. Nissan  Navara .. .. ..
73647364736            .. .. .. BMW     X5     .. .. ..
```

What I would like to know is what the top 2 models per brand are. I can groupby both columns and add a count no problem, but how do I then limit (or filter) that result? I.e. how do I keep the (up to) 2 most popular models per brand and remove the rest?

Whatever I try, I end up iterating over the brands that exist in the original dataframe manually. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `rank()` with Window and `filter()`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as func
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('a', 1, 1),
        ('a', 1, 2),
        ('a', 1, 3),
        ('a', 2, 1),
        ('a', 2, 2),
        ('a', 3, 1)
    ],
    schema=['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
)

df.printSchema()
df.show(10, False)
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|a   |1   |1   |
|a   |1   |2   |
|a   |1   |3   |
|a   |2   |1   |
|a   |2   |2   |
|a   |3   |1   |
+----+----+----+
```

where `col1` and `col2` are grouping columns and `col3` is your unique id:

```
df.groupBy(
    'col1', 'col2'
).agg(
    func.countDistinct('col3').alias('dcount')
).withColumn(
    'rank', func.rank().over(Window.partitionBy('col1').orderBy(func.desc('dcount')))
).filter(
    func.col('rank')<=2
).show(
    10, False
)
+----+----+------+----+
|col1|col2|dcount|rank|
+----+----+------+----+
|a   |1   |3     |1   |
|a   |2   |2     |2   |
+----+----+------+----+
```

You can use `rank()` after the grouping and aggregation to filter out the top 2 value in your each group (`col1`).

Comment: I'll have a play with rank. Thx. Maybe I didnt explain myself but the id is unique (more like a rowid) .. it wont appear more than once in the dataframe (unlike your example) - I thought mentioning it was perhaps useful in some way. The make, model & their combinations will appear multiple times.

Comment: @Lieuwe In my example data frame, `col3` is equivalent to your `id`. In fact, I can change my `col3` to a UUID, which is exactly the same to your case, and it still works, since I use countDistinct in my aggregation. I think you can test it directly in your case and it should work perfectly.